# Simplify mouseover/mouseout jQuery events? (a single event handler?)

Tags: events, jquery

the jquery is the best way to make beautyful effects

but I want to know if is't possible to reducing this code

```
$(function(){
    $("obj").mouseover(function(){
        // do something
    });
    $("obj").mouseout(function(){
        // ...
    });
});
```

to some thing like

```
$(function(){
    $("obj").mouseover(function(){
        // do something
    }else{
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: When you consider `mouseout` equal to `mouseleave`, use [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/): `$(function(){$("obj").hover(function(){/*mouseover*/},function(){/*mouseleave*/});});`

Comment: Is there any point though? Its much better to have code that is easier to read than cutting down your code and making it harder

Comment: That syntax won't even come close to working ;-) jQuery does not change JavaScript. `else` requires an `if`. Remember you can also chain: `$("obj").mouseover(...).mouseout(...)` (this works for many things in jQuery). Also, *any* (correctly designed) function-object will do, for instance: `$("obj").mouseover(myMouseOver)` (where `myMouseOver` evaluates to the applicable function-object)

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event which could take 2 callbacks:

```
$(function() {
    $("obj").hover(function() {
        // do something
    }, function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most jQuery functions return a reference to the Object they are attached to so you can actually do:

```
$("obj").mouseover(function(){
        ...
}).mouseout(function(){
        ...
});
```